# C Primer 5th - Task 14-6

Tags: c

A text file holds information about a softball team. Each line has data arranged as follows:

> 4 Jessie Joybat 5 2 1 1

The first item is the player's number, conveniently in the range 0–18. The second item is the player's first name, and the third is the player's last name. Each name is a single word. The next item is the player's official times at bat, followed by the number of hits, walks, and runs batted in (RBIs). The file may contain data for more than one game, so the same player may have more than one line of data, and there may be data for other players between those lines. Write a program that stores the data into an array of structures. The structure should have members to represent the first and last names, the at bats, hits, walks, and RBIs (runs batted in), and the batting average (to be calculated later). You can use the player number as an array index. The program should read to end-of-file, and it should keep cumulative totals for each player.

The world of baseball statistics is an involved one. For example, a walk or reaching base on an error doesn't count as an at-bat but could possibly produce an RBI. But all this program has to do is read and process the data file, as described next, without worrying about how realistic the data is.

The simplest way for the program to proceed is to initialize the structure contents to zeros, read the file data into temporary variables, and then add them to the contents of the corresponding structure. After the program has finished reading the file, it should then calculate the batting average for each player and store it in the corresponding structure member. The batting average is calculated by dividing the cumulative number of hits for a player by the cumulative number of at-bats; it should be a floating-point calculation. The program should then display the cumulative data for each player along with a line showing the combined statistics for the entire team.

---

team.txt (text file I'm working with):

```
4 Jessie Joybat 5 2 1 1
4 Jessie Joybat 7 3 5 3
7 Jack Donner 6 3 1 2
11 Martin Garder 4 3 2 1
15 Jaime Curtis 7 4 1 2
2 Curtis Michel 3 2 2 3
9 Gillan Morthim 9 6 6 7
12 Brett Tyler 8 7 4 3
8 Hans Gunner 7 7 2 3
14 Jessie James 11 2 3 4 
12 Brett Tyler 4 3 1 3
```

---

Since I'm a beginner in C, either I misinterpreted the task from what was asked originally or it's unfairly complex (I believe the former is the case). I'm so lost that I can't think of the way how could I fill in by the criteria of index (player number) every piece of data, keep track of whether he has more than one game, calculate and fetch bat average and then print.

What I have so far is:

```
#define LGT 30
struct profile {
     int pl_num;
     char name[LGT];
     char lname[LGT];
     int atbat[LGT/3];
     int hits[LGT/3];
     int walks[LGT/3];
     int runs[LGT/3];
     float batavg;
};

//It's wrong obviously but it's a starting point
int main(void)
{
    FILE *flx;
    int i,jc,flow=0;
    struct profile stat[LGT]={{0}};

    if((flx=fopen("team.txt","r"))==NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Can't read file team!\n");
        exit(1);      
    }

    for( jc = 0; jc < 11;  jc++) {
        fscanf(flx,"%d",&i);
        stat[i].pl_num=i;

        fscanf(flx,"%s",&stat[i].name);
        fscanf(flx,"%s",&stat[i].lname);

        fscanf(flx,"%d",&stat[i].atbat[flow]);
        fscanf(flx,"%d",&stat[i].hits[flow]);
        fscanf(flx,"%d",&stat[i].walks[flow]);
        fscanf(flx,"%d",&stat[i].runs[flow]);
        flow++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to verify: If I were to print this list out for you, could you solve the problem with pen and paper? If not, what is it you don't understand? If you could, what is it you don't understand about writing code to do it for you?

Comment: As I said I'm a beginner, that's all I can say to you, either give some tracks or don't bother!

Comment: Wow, calm down, take a deep breath....exhale. Especially with beginners asking homework questions it is nice to know if they grasp the problem at hand and simply have difficulty translating it into code, or if they have not yet understood what it is they are asked to do. I merely tried to verify which of those two it was because they require different answers. Besides that it's my experience that trusty old pen and paper are used far too little by new programmers who often get bogged down by trying to program their way out of a problem. Once you're really a high level coder, you'll get this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Advice 1: don't declare arrays like `atbat[LGT/3]`.

Advice 2: Instead of multiple `fscanf` you could read the whole line in a shot.

Advice 3: Since the number of players is limited and the player number has a good range (0-18), using that player number as an index into the struct array is a good idea.

Advice 4: Since you need cumulative data for each player (no need to store his history points), then you don't need arrays of integers, just an integer to represent the total.

So:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define PLAYERS_NO  19

typedef struct  
{
     char name[20+1];
     char lastName[25+1];
     int atbat;
     int hits;
     int walks;
     int runs;
     float batavg;
} Profile;



int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Profile stats[PLAYERS_NO];
    int i;
    FILE* dataFile;

    int playerNo;
    Profile tmpProfile;
    int games = 0;


    for(i=0; i<PLAYERS_NO; ++i)
    {
        stats[i].name[0] = '\0';
        stats[i].lastName[0] = '\0';
        stats[i].atbat = 0;
        stats[i].hits = 0;
        stats[i].walks = 0;
        stats[i].runs = 0;
    }

    dataFile = fopen("team.txt", "r");
    if ( dataFile == NULL )
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't read file team!\n");
        exit(1);    
     }

     for(i=0; i<PLAYERS_NO && !feof(dataFile); ++i, ++games)
     {
        fscanf(dataFile, "%d", &playerNo);
        if ( playerNo <0 || playerNo > PLAYERS_NO )
        {
           fprintf(stderr, "Player number out of range\n");
           continue;
        }

        fscanf(dataFile, "%s %s %d %d %d %d", 
            &tmpProfile.name,
            &tmpProfile.lastName,
            &tmpProfile.atbat,
            &tmpProfile.hits,
            &tmpProfile.walks,
            &tmpProfile.runs);

        printf("READ: %d %s %s %d %d %d %d\n", 
            playerNo,
            tmpProfile.name,
            tmpProfile.lastName,
            tmpProfile.atbat,
            tmpProfile.hits,
            tmpProfile.walks,
            tmpProfile.runs);


        strcpy(stats[playerNo].name, tmpProfile.name);
        strcpy(stats[playerNo].lastName, tmpProfile.lastName);

        stats[playerNo].atbat += tmpProfile.atbat;
        stats[playerNo].hits += tmpProfile.hits;
        stats[playerNo].walks += tmpProfile.walks;
        stats[playerNo].runs += tmpProfile.runs;
    }

    /* exercise: compute the average */
    fclose(dataFile);

    for(i=0; i<PLAYERS_NO; ++i)
    {
        if ( stats[i].name[0] == '\0' )
            continue;

        printf("%d %s %s %d %d %d %d\n",
            i,
            stats[i].name,
            stats[i].lastName,
            stats[i].atbat,
            stats[i].hits,
            stats[i].walks,
            stats[i].runs);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I've changed the `memset` with a loop because this is a homework. The `memset` is probably cleaner and faster: `memset(stats, 0, sizeof(Profile) * PLAYERS_NO);`

Answer (score 0):

The first rule of programming: Divide and conquer.

So you need to identify individual operations. One such operation is "load one row of input", another is "look up a player". If you have some of those operations (more will come up as you go), you can start building your program:

```
while( more_input ) {
    row = load_one_row()
    player = find_player( row.name )
    if( !player ) {
        player = create_player( row.name )
        add_player( player )
    }

    ... do something with row and player ...
}
```

when you have that, you can start to write all the functions.

An important point here is to write test cases. Start with a simple input and test the code to read a row. Do you get the correct results?

If so, test the code to find/create players.

The test cases make sure that you can forget about code that already works.

Use a framework like [Check](http://check.sourceforge.net/) for this.

Answer (score 0):

If I were doing this, I'd start with a structure that only held one "set" of data, then create an array of those structs:

```
struct profile {
     char name[NAMELEN];
     char lname[NAMELEN];
     int atbat;
     int hits;
     int walks;
     int runs;
     float batavg;
};
```

Since you're using the player's number as the index into an array, you don't need to store it into the structure too.

I think that will simplify the problem a little bit. You don't need to store multiple data items for a single player -- when you get a duplicate, you just ignore some of the new data (like the names, which should be identical) and sum up the others (e.g., at-bats, hits).